# Mockito, how to verify if the method of the tested class was called?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I want to check if toDishResponseDTO was called during a method execution. But it's not possible since this is a method of the class being tested. How can this be done?

Class

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class DishServiceTest {
    @Mock
    DishRepository dishRepository;
    @Mock
    RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;


    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    DishService dishService;
```

Method under test

```
    public List<DishResponseDTO> getAll() {
    List<Dish> dishlsit = dishRepository.findAll();
    return dishlsit.stream()
            .map(this::toDishResponseDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Test

```
    @Test
void shouldCallFindAllReturnDto_whenV() {
    Mockito.when(dishRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(TestData.ENTITY_DISH);
    dishService.getAll();
    Mockito.verify(dishRepository, times(1)).findAll();
    Mockito.verify(dishService times(6)).toDishResponseDTO(any()); // compile error, because verify can be called only on mocks
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use Mockito to verify that method is called, but you can verify the output from the `getAll()` method given that you've mocked out the response to `dishRepository.findAll()`.  So, in effect, just add some assertions after your verify calls that match your expected data with the actual data, I assume that `this::toDishResponseDTO` just return a `Dish`.

```
@Test
void shouldCallFindAllReturnDto_whenV() {
   Mockito.when(dishRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(TestData.ENTITY_DISH);
   List<Dish> dishes = dishService.getAll();
   Mockito.verify(dishRepository, times(1)).findAll();
   assertThat(dishes, is(notNullValue());
   assertThat(dishes.get(0).getSomeField, is(equalTo("someValue")));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, all my Service methods return the result of the toDishResponseDTO() and I thought it would be good if I could just check if that method is called.
And check toDishResponseDTO() once instead of checking it every method.
it's a pity that such a useful feature is missing

Comment: If this is something that you must do, you can look into PowerMock, it has the ability to perform the verifications that you want.  Keep in mind though, what you really want to test are your public methods and that they're producing the desired output, verifying the response data covers this.